# Sorting pandas dataframe per group and keep desired order

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Junk":list("aaaaaabbbcccc"),
    "Region":['West','West','West','West','East','East','East','South','South','South','North','North','North'],
    "Sales":[1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 5, 7, 9, 7, 5, 9, 5]
})

+------+--------+-------+
| Junk | Region | Sales |
+------+--------+-------+
| a    | West   |     1 |
| a    | West   |     3 |
| a    | West   |     4 |
| a    | West   |     2 |
| a    | East   |     4 |
| a    | East   |     2 |
| b    | East   |     5 |
| b    | South  |     7 |
| b    | South  |     9 |
| c    | South  |     7 |
| c    | North  |     5 |
| c    | North  |     9 |
| c    | North  |     5 |
+------+--------+-------+
```

I am trying to do two things

1. Sort the dataframe based on each Region

I am able to achieve it with below code

```
df.sort_values(by = ['Region','Sales'])


+------+--------+-------+
| Junk | Region | Sales |
+------+--------+-------+
| a    | East   |     2 |
| a    | East   |     4 |
| b    | East   |     5 |
| c    | North  |     5 |
| c    | North  |     5 |
| c    | North  |     9 |
| b    | South  |     7 |
| c    | South  |     7 |
| b    | South  |     9 |
| a    | West   |     1 |
| a    | West   |     2 |
| a    | West   |     3 |
| a    | West   |     4 |
+------+--------+-------+
```

But I want to retain the order of `Region` column. `West` should be first, then `East`, then `South` and then `North`

Desired Output

```
+--------+----------+---------+
|  Junk  |  Region  |  Sales  |
+--------+----------+---------+
|  a     | West     |       1 |
|  a     | West     |       2 |
|  a     | West     |       3 |
|  a     | West     |       4 |
|  a     | East     |       2 |
|  a     | East     |       4 |
|  b     | East     |       5 |
|  b     | South    |       7 |
|  c     | South    |       7 |
|  b     | South    |       9 |
|  c     | North    |       5 |
|  c     | North    |       5 |
|  c     | North    |       9 |
+--------+----------+---------+
```

2. I just want to sort the `Region = East` and `Region  = North` rest of the regions should be the way they are

Desired Output:

```
+--------+----------+---------+
|  Junk  |  Region  |  Sales  |
+--------+----------+---------+
|  a     | West     |       1 |
|  a     | West     |       3 |
|  a     | West     |       4 |
|  a     | West     |       2 |
|  a     | East     |       2 |
|  a     | East     |       4 |
|  b     | East     |       5 |
|  b     | South    |       7 |
|  b     | South    |       9 |
|  c     | South    |       7 |
|  c     | North    |       5 |
|  c     | North    |       5 |
|  c     | North    |       9 |
+--------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: so what's the final desired output?

Comment: `df.sort_values(by = ['Region','Sales']).loc[['West', 'East', 'South', 'North'], :]` will give you the ordering in way you want and for your point 2 i think you can do `df[(df.Region=='East') &  (df.Region=='North')]..sort_values(by = ['Region','Sales'])` but if you want to retain the dataframe then make seperate and then append two data frames

Comment: let me know if it works for you then i will post the full as answer

Comment: @PuneetSinha It gives me `"None of [['West', 'East', 'South', 'North']] are in the [index]"
` error

Comment: Is there any builtin way rather than specifying it manually ?

Comment: try this df.set_index(["Region"]) @Rookie_123

Comment: you can sort it alphabetically ... there is no other way , as far as i know.. and you have to set region as index then you will not get the error

Comment: to avoid confusion can you post your expected dataframe please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create [ordered categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) column first and then sorting:

```
order = ['West', 'East', 'South', 'North']
df['Region'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['Region'], ordered=True, categories=order)

df = df.sort_values(by = ['Region','Sales'])
print (df)
   Junk Region  Sales
0     a   West      1
3     a   West      2
1     a   West      3
2     a   West      4
5     a   East      2
4     a   East      4
6     b   East      5
7     b  South      7
9     c  South      7
8     b  South      9
10    c  North      5
12    c  North      5
11    c  North      9
```

Solution with `map` by dictionary with create new column, order and then remove helper column:

```
order = {'West':1, 'East':2, 'South':3, 'North':4}

df = df.assign(tmp=df['Region'].map(order)).sort_values(by = ['tmp','Sales']).drop('tmp', 1)
print (df)
   Junk Region  Sales
6     a   West      1
0     a   West      2
7     a   West      3
8     a   West      4
2     a   East      2
1     a   East      4
3     b   East      5
4     b  South      7
9     c  South      7
5     b  South      9
10    c  North      5
12    c  North      5
11    c  North      9
```

For second is necessary sorting by filtered rows, but assign numpy array for prevent data alignment:

```
order = ['West', 'East', 'South', 'North']
df['Region'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['Region'], ordered=True, categories=order)

mask = df['Region'].isin(['North', 'East'])
df[mask] = df[mask].sort_values(['Region','Sales']).values
print (df)
   Junk Region  Sales
0     a   West      1
1     a   West      3
2     a   West      4
3     a   West      2
4     a   East      2
5     a   East      4
6     b   East      5
7     b  South      7
8     b  South      9
9     c  South      7
10    c  North      5
11    c  North      5
12    c  North      9
```

`map` alternative:

```
order = {'East':1, 'North':2}
df = df.assign(tmp=df['Region'].map(order))

mask = df['Region'].isin(['North', 'East'])
df[mask] = df[mask].sort_values(['tmp','Sales']).values
df = df.drop('tmp', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` and take advantage of `sort` parameter. Then use `apply` and `sort_values` with a conditional:

```
sort_regions = ['North', 'East']
df.groupby('Region', sort=False).apply(
    lambda x: x.sort_values('Sales')
    if x['Region'].iloc[0] in sort_regions
    else x
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   Junk Region  Sales
0     a   West      1
1     a   West      3
2     a   West      4
3     a   West      2
4     a   East      2
5     a   East      4
6     b   East      5
7     b  South      7
8     b  South      9
9     c  South      7
10    c  North      5
11    c  North      5
12    c  North      9
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a mapping between `west`, `east`, `south` and `north` to 0, 1, 2, 3

```
>>> my_order = ['West','East','South','North']
>>> order = {key: i for i, key in enumerate(my_order)}
>>> order
{'West': 0, 'East': 1, 'South': 2, 'North': 3}
```

And use the mapping for sorting key:

```
>>> df.iloc[df['Region'].map(order).sort_values().index]
```

Comment: I am getting same dataframe as my input dataframe

Comment: @Rookie_123 my_order = ['West','East','South','North']